# phpmyadmin apache configuration index.php

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I was trying to use phpMyAdmin with Apache hence downloaded them, read online that i have to change index.html to index.php to get the correct pg when accessing localhost/phpmyadmin. However when i do that something else appears...helpp me!

It says this when i type localhost/phpmyadmin,

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * display Git revision if requested
 */
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',
    'collation_connection',
    'db',
    'table'
);
foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);

/*
 * Black list of all scripts to which front-end must submit data.
 * Such scripts must not be loaded on home page.
 *
 */
 $target_blacklist = array (
    'import.php', 'export.php'
    );

// If we have a valid target, let's load that script instead
if (! empty($_REQUEST['target'])
    && is_string($_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! preg_match('/^index/', $_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $target_blacklist)
    && in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $goto_whitelist)
) {
    include $_REQUEST['target'];
    exit;
}

// See FAQ 1.34
if (! empty($_REQUEST['db'])) {
    $page = null;
    if (! empty($_REQUEST['table'])) {
        $page = $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabTable'];
    } else {
        $page = $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase'];
    }
    include $page;
    exit;
}

/**
 * Check if it is an ajax request to reload the recent tables list.
 */
require_once 'libraries/RecentFavoriteTable.class.php';
if ($GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] && ! empty($_REQUEST['recent_table'])) {
    $response = PMA_Response::getInstance();
    $response->addJSON(
        'list',
        PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList()
    );
    exit;
}

if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) {
        PMA_printGitRevision();
        exit;
    }
    echo '<div id="is_git_revision"></div>';
}
more.....
```

Comment: You need to enable the Apache PHP module. Right now Apache doesn't know that .php files should be interpreted as PHP scripts, so you're just getting the text output.

Comment: It's all documented here : http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php
My guess would be that PHP module isn't loaded (see step 7), check your `httpd.conf`, which is usually located in `/etc/apache2/`, it should contain this line : `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` which enables PHP module in your Apache server. You also need to tell Apache how to handle PHP files, see step 8 of the link above. Oh and don't forget to restart your Apache server once you're done with the configuration !

Comment: i have solved e prob...thanks anyways everyone (: